# async SQLAlchemy can't create engine

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, psycopg2, asyncpg

I've made a small app, that uses `SQLAlchemy` to handle connection with postgresql database. Now I want to rewrite it using asincio. For some reason, when I run it, i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Space\discord_count_bot\bot\bot\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    dbConnection.init_connection(
  File "D:\Space\discord_count_bot\bot\bot\db_hanler.py", line 78, in init_connection
    engine = create_async_engine(connection_string, future=True, echo=True)
  File "D:\Space\discord_count_bot\bot_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\engine.py", line 40, in create_async_engine
    sync_engine = _create_engine(*arg, **kw)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "D:\Space\discord_count_bot\bot_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Space\discord_count_bot\bot_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 560, in create_engine
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "D:\Space\discord_count_bot\bot_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\psycopg2.py", line 782, in dbapi
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

And if `psycopg2` is installed, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Space\discord_count_bot\bot\bot\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    dbConnection.init_connection(
  File "D:\Space\discord_count_bot\bot\bot\db_hanler.py", line 78, in init_connection
    engine = create_async_engine(connection_string, future=True, echo=True)
  File "D:\Space\discord_count_bot\bot_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\engine.py", line 41, in create_async_engine
    return AsyncEngine(sync_engine)
  File "D:\Space\discord_count_bot\bot_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\engine.py", line 598, in __init__
    raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: The asyncio extension requires an async driver to be used. The loaded 'psycopg2' is not async.
```

I got `asyncpg` installed, I guess, I need to specificaly tell `SQLAlchemy` to use it. Or maybe, there is something in my code, that makes `SQLAlchemy` think, it should use `psycopg2`... I cant find anything about it, in every tutorial I've encountered everething seems to work just fine.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import logging

from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import select, and_
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Boolean

logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
Base = declarative_base()


class TaskModel(Base):
    """Counting task model for database."""

    __tablename__ = 'tasks'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = Column(String(200))
    channel_id = Column(Integer)
    is_dm = Column(Boolean)
    start_time = Column(DateTime)
    end_time = Column(DateTime)
    count = Column(Integer)
    canceled = Column(Boolean)


class DBConnection:
    """Class handles all the db operations."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Create new uninitialized handler."""
        self._session: AsyncSession = None

    def init_connection(self, user, password, host, port, db):
        """Connect to actual database."""
        connection_string = "postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}".format(
            user, password, host, port, db
        )
        engine = create_async_engine(connection_string, future=True, echo=True)
        self._session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)

    async def add_task(self, author, channel_id, count, is_dm):
        """Add new task to db."""
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        task = TaskModel(
            author=author,
            channel_id=channel_id,
            is_dm=is_dm,
            start_time=now,
            end_time=now + timedelta(seconds=count),
            count=count,
            canceled=False
        )
        self._session.add(task)
        await self._session.commit()
        logger.info(f"task added to db: {task}")
        return task

    async def get_active_tasks(self):
        """Get all active tasks."""
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        async with self._session() as session:
            query = select(TaskModel).where(and_(
                    TaskModel.end_time > now,
                    TaskModel.canceled == False
            ))
            result = await session.execute(query)
            return result.fetchall()

dbConnection = DBConnection()
```

Comment: Try `postgresql+asyncpg://…`

Comment: pyscopg2 is the default driver SQLAlchemy uses for Postgres. As mentioned, if you want to use anything else you have to specify it in the connection string.

Comment: An example can be seen [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/asyncio.html).

Comment: Gord Thompson, you are my saviour, thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Gord Thompson said, I needed to be more specific in my connection string,  `postgresql+asyncpg://…` did the trick, thank you)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this. You can't think how much time I have spent trying to thing what's going on.